# c# wpf window opacity change error

Tags: c#, wpf, window, opacity

I'm working on a c# project with WPF but I've a problem and this makes me crazy :)
Here is the problem. I'm trying to change new window's opacity with timer. But when I run the project, "this.Opacity += .1;" code throws an exception like "Invalid operation etc..." 
I'm opening a window from MainWindow.cs file with this code:

```
private void MenuItemArchiveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var archiveWindow = new ArchiveWindow();
        var screenSize = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        archiveWindow.Width = (screenSize.Width * 95) / 100;
        archiveWindow.Height = (screenSize.Height * 90) / 100;
        archiveWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        archiveWindow.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);
        archiveWindow.AllowsTransparency = true;
        archiveWindow.Opacity = 0.1;
        archiveWindow.Topmost = true;
        archiveWindow.Show();
    }
```

My ArchiveWindow code is,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace POCentury
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ArchiveWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ArchiveWindow : Window
    {
        Timer timer1 = new Timer();

        public ArchiveWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Interval = 1 * 1000;
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(opacityChange);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.AutoReset = false;
            timer1.Start();

        }
        private void opacityChange(object sender, EventArgs a)
        {
            if (this.Opacity == 1)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                this.Opacity += .1;
            }

        }
        private void ArchiveWindowClose()
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }
        private void btnArchiveWindowClose(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ArchiveWindowClose();
        }

        private void imgPatternClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("sd");  
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me with doing that? 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't access the timer inside the opacityChange event because it's happening in a different thread. You need the Dispatcher to do that.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
        if (this.Opacity == 1)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Opacity += .1;
        }
}));
```

Comment: Can you explain why you did that?

Comment: I've updated with explanation. If you want to know more, read http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/archive/2010/06/06/understanding-dispatcher-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: First of all I'd like to thank you for your quick answer.
It was working very good for starter but, I've moved all of the animation code to new Calss file. Now program gives that error Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Delegate, params object[])' can you help me?

Comment: You probably need to make the method static. If that's not it, ask a new question as it's a different issue.